# How to combine rows based on unique values in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm a pretty beginner at R. I've a CSV file where data is as follows, for example:

```
ID  Values
820 D1,D2,FE
730 D1,D2,D3,PC,Io,He,Bt,Te,AR,PG
730 DV,GTH,LYT
567 EDR,TYU,EOP,OMN
567 FGH,KIH,IOP
```

I want to remove the duplicates in `ID` and append their data into its `Values` column, like this:

```
ID  Values
820 D1,D2,FE
730 D1,D2,D3,PC,Io,He,Bt,Te,AR,PG,DV,GTH,LYT
567 EDR,TYU,EOP,OMN,FGH,KIH,IOP
```

How to achieve this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dat <- read.table(text="ID  Values
820 D1,D2,FE
730 D1,D2,D3,PC,Io,He,Bt,Te,AR,PG
730 DV,GTH,LYT
567 EDR,TYU,EOP,OMN
567 FGH,KIH,IOP", header=TRUE)

dat2 <- dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(val=paste(Values, collapse=","))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Values=paste(Values, collapse=",")) ,ID]
```

Or using `base R`

```
 aggregate(.~ID, df1, paste, collapse=",")
```